# Potentially undefined variable

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

I'm getting keys from global variable that is potentially not defined. Keys may not exist, too:

```
import { get } from 'lodash/fp';

const probablyGlobalFoo = typeof globalFoo === 'undefined' ? void 0 : globalFoo;

const baz = get('baz', probablyGlobalFoo) || get('bar.baz', probablyGlobalFoo) || 'baz';
```

`typeof globalFoo === 'undefined'` check is idiomatic to JavaScript but is clumsy and verbose. This case occurs a couple of times in my code base but not often enough to introduce another helper function to my utils library. I would prefer to just provide getter function instead that is handled properly, something like:

```
getFromAGetterAndCatchIfNotDefined('bar.baz', () => globalFoo);
```

Is there a straightforward way to handle this case with Lodash FP or Ramda APIs I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your global variable is defined on `window` (in the case of global `var`), you can check for `window.globalFoo` (or `global.globalFoo` in nodejs). If not you'll have to use the `typeof` check.

To check for a property that doesn't exist in an object, or an undefined variable, you can use lodash/fp's [`getOr()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1980#issuecomment-182594539):

```js
const { getOr } = _;

console.log(getOr('baz', 'bar.baz', window.globalFoo));

const anotherValue = { bar: { baz: 5 } }

console.log(getOr('baz', 'bar.baz', anotherValue));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

Or lodash's [`get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get):

```js
const { get } = _;

console.log(get(window.globalFoo, 'bar.baz', 'baz'));

const anotherValue = { bar: { baz: 5 } }

console.log(get(anotherValue, 'bar.baz', 'baz'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js)"></script>
```

Or ramda's [`pathOr()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathOr):

```js
const { pathOr } = R;

console.log(pathOr('baz', ['bar','baz'], window.globalFoo));

const anotherValue = { bar: { baz: 5 } }

console.log(pathOr('baz', ['bar','baz'], anotherValue));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The reason why I didn't use `window` is that the code is platform-agnostic, and I didn't want to encumber it with `window` vs `global` detection because it's specifically `globalFoo` I'm after. Thanks for `getOr`/`pathOr` hint.

Comment: Unless it's something very unique, you can decide between `global` and `window` by using something like [this](https://github.com/purposeindustries/window-or-global/blob/master/lib/index.js).

Comment: I prefer to avoid this kind of detection where possible, considering we have browsers with `global` variable defined and Node environments with `window`. Any way, seems like `typeof` is the way. `R.tryCatch` is the only relevant thing I found, and it results in more verbose code.